# sorting linked list simplest way

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I am trying to code very basic sorting method for linked lists. I am getting unhandled exception. What is the mistake i am making? Here is my code:-

```
struct LinkedNode// structure for linked list
{
    int data;
    struct LinkedNode *next;
}* start = NULL;
```

following function creates a linked list

```
void CreateLinkedList()
{
    LinkedNode *newNode, *current;
    printf("enter 5 numbers to create linked list\n");
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        newNode = (struct LinkedNode *)malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));
        scanf("%d", &newNode->data);
        newNode->next = NULL;
        if(start == NULL)
        {
            start = newNode;
            current = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            current->next = newNode;
            current = newNode;
        }
    }
}
```

following function is used for sorting the linked list nodes

```
void SortLinkedList()
{
    struct LinkedNode *node=NULL, *temp = NULL;
    int tempvar;//temp variable to store node data
    node = start;
    temp = node->next;//temp node to hold node data and next link
    while(node != NULL && node->next != NULL)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++)//value 5 because I am taking only 5 nodes
        {
            if(node->data > temp->data)//swap node data
            {
                tempvar = node->data;
                node->data = temp->data;
                temp->data = tempvar;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `start`? How is created and inited?

Comment: 'What is the mistake i am making?' : not debugging your code.

Comment: Show at least an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please show also the typedef of `LinkedNode`. And also the exception message.

Comment: the sorting algorithm that is best suited for linked lists is probably [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This code

```
void SortLinkedList()
    {
    struct LinkedNode *node=NULL, *temp = NULL;
    int tempvar;//temp variable to store node data
    node = start;
    //temp = node;//temp node to hold node data and next link
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        temp=node; 
        while (temp->next !=NULL)//travel till the second last element 
        {
           if(temp->data > temp->next->data)// compare the data of the nodes 
            {
              tempvar = temp->data;
              temp->data = temp->next->data;// swap the data
              temp->next->data = tempvar;
            }
         temp = temp->next;    // move to the next element 
        }
        node = node->next;    // move to the next node
    }
}
```

1 - outer while loop is use for the total number of pass that will require to sort the linked list..

2- In second while loop we are actually comparing the data of the nodes that we want to sort

Comment: in this code, are we swapping the data or just the next pointers?

Comment: Swapping the data only If You want to swap the next pointer then that also can be done .....but in your given code your swapping data only ....so i have given code that way :)

Comment: It should print the linked list in the sorted sequence....I hope your calling `display()` function after calling `SortLinkedList()` function

Comment: I voted down because code only answers without any explanation aren't considered useful answers. (There's a meta post on this)

Comment: @DanielJour I have added comment in the code to explain code :)

Comment: Please explain what and where is it wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of implementing your own sort, you can just use `qsort`. Of course, `qsort` requires an array, but that is easy enough to create.

In this case, you know that the list has 5 members. But, if you didn't know, you could just count them.

```
int size_of_list = 0;
struct LinkedNode *p;

for (p = start; p != NULL; p = p->next) ++size_of_list;

if (size_of_list == 0) {
    // Nothing to do
    return;
}
```

Now you can create your array;

```
struct LinkedNode *arr[size_of_list + 1], **arrp = arr;
for (p = start; p != NULL; p = p->next) *arrp++ = p;
*arrp = NULL;
```

Then, use `qsort` on `arr`. There are lots of examples, but the trick is writing an appropriate comparison function.

```
int cmp_LinkedNode(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const struct LinkedNode * const *aa = a;
    const struct LinkedNode * const *bb = b;
    return ((*aa)->data > (*bb)->data) - ((*aa)->data < (*bb)->data);
}

//...
qsort(arr, size_of_list, sizeof(*arr), cmp_LinkedNode);
```

And then, rewire the list into the sorted order.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size_of_list; ++i) arr[i]->next = arr[i+1];
start = arr[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

yeah sorting a linked list using nodes/links is a pretty hard job. Spend hours doing it myself but since i have done it why not help others..
What you need to do is simply find the minimum value in your list. Swap it with the head node and the recur for head->next.
The code for sort is only of 3 to 4 lines if you have FindMin() and Swap() functions made..
here is the complete code for sort(),swap()and findmin().

```
void sort(node **start)
{
    if (((*start)->next == NULL) || (*start == NULL))
    {
        return;
    }
    node *min = findmin(*start);
    swap(*start, min, start);
    sort(&((*start)->next));
}

void swap(node *p1, node *p2, node **start)
{
    node *p1pre = NULL;
    node *p1curr = *start;
    while (p1curr!=p1)
    {
        p1pre = p1curr;
        p1curr = p1curr->next;
    }
    node *p2pre = NULL;
    node *p2curr = *start;
    while (p2curr != p2)
    {
        p2pre = p2curr;
        p2curr = p2curr->next;
    }
    if (p1pre != NULL)
    {
        p1pre->next = p2curr;
    }
    else
    {
        *start = p2curr;
    }
    if (p2pre != NULL)
    {
        p2pre->next = p1curr;
    }
    else
    {
        *start = p1curr;
    }
    node *temp = p2curr->next;
    p2curr->next = p1curr->next;
    p1curr->next = temp;
}

node* findmin(node *start)
{
    int flag = 0;
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        cout << "list is empty" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        node *curr = start->next;
        node *min = start;
        while (curr->next != NULL)
        {
            if (min->value > curr->value)
            {
                min = curr;
                flag++;
            }
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        if ((curr->next == NULL) && (min->value > curr->value))
        {
            min = curr;
            flag++;
        }
        if (flag > 0)
        {
            return min;
        }
    }
}
```