# How can I sort a Linked List with User inputs?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a project, that generates a Linked List, delete them and show this at the User. Now, I want to sort the list.
My struct:

```
typedef struct YugiohCard {
    char Name[100];
    char CardType[20];
    int Level;
    int Rank;
    int PendulumStage;
    int Link;
    int ATK;
    int DEF;
    char Property[20];
    char MonsterType[40];
    char CardType2[30];
    char Description[500];
    struct YugiohCard* pNext;
    struct YugiohCard* pPrev;
} struYugiohCard;
```

When the User says: "CardType2 Ascending" then the program sort the list by CardType2 and Ascending.

In this case alphematicaly. It is also possible to sort by the other struct contents(Monstertyp, ATK, DEF, etc.). Ascending or Descending.

How can I do it without things from C++?

Sorry for my bad English. I'm not very well at this.

***Edit:***
Here is my complete Code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "time.h"

typedef struct YugiohCard {
    char Name[100];
    char CardType[20];
    int Level;
    int Rank;
    int PendulumStage;
    int Link;
    int ATK;
    int DEF;
    char Property[20];
    char MonsterType[40];
    char CardType2[30];
    char Description[500];
    struct YugiohCard* pNext;
    struct YugiohCard* pPrev;
} struYugiohCard;

bool OutputList(struYugiohCard* pStart)
{
    int count = 0;
    struYugiohCard* current = pStart;  // Initialize current 
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        current = current->pNext;
    }

    char answer[265];
    int CountetCardsThatWillBeOutputet;
    printf("How many Yugioh cards would you like to spend? 0 means all, 
            otherwise the number counts. Number of elements in list: %i Input:", 
            count);
    fgets(answer, 265, stdin);
    CountetCardsThatWillBeOutputet = atoi(answer);
    int countOutputetCards = 0;

    if (CountetCardsThatWillBeOutputet > count)
    {
        printf("Please enter a correct number!");
        system("pause");
        return false;
    }
    else if (CountetCardsThatWillBeOutputet == 0)
    {
        CountetCardsThatWillBeOutputet = count;
    }

    system("cls");
    printf("%10s %20s %10s %10s %20s %10s %10s %10s %20s %20s %20s %20s\n", 
    "Name", "CardType", "Level", "Rank", "PendulumStage", "Link", "ATK", 
    "DEF", "Property", "MonsterType", "CardType2", "Description");
    for (struYugiohCard* pOut = pStart; pOut != NULL; pOut = pOut->pNext)
    {
        printf("%10s %20s %10i %10i %20i %10i %10i %10i %20s %20s %20s 
                %20s\n", pOut->Name, pOut->CardType, pOut->Level, pOut- 
                >Rank, pOut->PendelumStage, pOut->Link, pOut->ATK, pOut->DEF, 
                pOut->Property, pOut->MonsterType, pOut->CardType2, pOut- 
                >Description);
        countOutputetCards++;
        if (countOutputetCards == CountetCardsThatWillBeOutputet )
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}

void DeleteList(struYugiohCard** head_ref)
{
    struct YugiohCard* prev = *head_ref;

    while (*head_ref)
    {
        *head_ref = (*head_ref)->pNext;
        free(prev);
        prev = *head_ref;
    }
}

struYugiohCard* CreateList()
{
    system("cls");
    char answer[265];
    int countedCards;
    printf("\nHow many Yugioh cards would you like to create? Please enter 
            only enter numbers, otherwise you'll crash.");
    fgets(answer, 265, stdin);
    countedCards = atoi(answer);

    struYugiohCard* pFirst = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < countedCards; i++)
    {
        struYugiohCard* pNew = 
            (struYugiohCard*)malloc(sizeof(struYugiohCard));
        if (pNew == NULL) break;
        pNew->Name[0] = 'A' + rand() % 26;
        pNew->Name[1] = '\0';
        pNew->CardType[0] = 'A' + rand() % 26;
        pNew->CardType[1] = '\0';
        pNew->Level = 1 + rand() % 12;
        pNew->Rank = 1 + rand() % 13;
        pNew->PendulumStage = 1 + rand() % 12;
        pNew->Link = 1 + rand() % 8;
        pNew->ATK = rand() % 10001;
        pNew->DEF = rand() % 10001;
        pNew->Property[0] = 'A' + rand() % 26;
        pNew->Property[1] = '\0';
        pNew->MonsterType[0] = 'A' + rand() % 26;
        pNew->MonsterType[1] = '\0';
        pNew->CardType2[0] = 'A' + rand() % 26;
        pNew->CardType2[1] = '\0';
        pNew->Description[0] = 'A' + rand() % 26;
        pNew->Description[1] = '\0';
        if (pFirst != NULL)
        {
            pNew->pNext = pFirst;
        }
        else
        {
            pNew->pNext = NULL;
        }
        pFirst = pNew;
    }
    return pFirst;
}

int main()
{   
    struYugiohCard* pStart = NULL;
    printf("\nIMPORTANT: Please maximize the window, otherwise it will not 
            represents everything correctly.");
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\nDo you want to create a Yugioh card list (YKE) that 
                Delete Yugioh card list(YKL), a single Yugioh card 
                delete(EYKL), sort the list(YKS), the Yugioh- 
                Output card list(YKA) or the program 
                close(Prsc):");
        char answer[265];
        fgets(answer, 265, stdin);
        if (strcmp(answer, "YKE\n") == 0)
        {
            pStart = CreateList();
        }
        else if (strcmp(answer, "YKS\n") == 0)
        {
            //SortList(pStart);
        }
        else if (strcmp(answer, "EYKL\n") == 0)
        {
            //DeleteOneCard(pStart);
        }
        else if (strcmp(answer, "YKL\n") == 0)
        {
            DeleteList(&pStart);
        }
        else if (strcmp(answer, "YKA\n") == 0)
        {
            OutputList(pStart);
        }
        else if (strcmp(answer, "Prsc\n") == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Please enter a shortcut!");
        }
    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: Create an array of pointers. Have the array members point to the list members. Then follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23689916/315052). Then, string the list members into the sorted order.

Comment: First, the list exist already, but I need it to sort. I also not understand the answer. I'm new in C. Please an Example with a String and Integer ASC and DESC. And Explain how it works.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914574/sorting-linked-list-simplest-way/52025806) helps

Comment: @Jabberwocky, Sorry no. In your comment Link, the questioner have one struct content and I have 12. That help with one, but not with 12.

Comment: @a.b_om it doesn't matter if the struct has 1 or 100 fields, you're dealing with _pointers_ here.

Comment: @a.b_om As Jabberwocky pointed out, it does not make any difference at all, so I closed this as a duplicate.

Comment: I know that I can use it, but it isn't dynamic. I must make this 12 times and that is not a beautiful code. I ask for a variable variant. When it doesnt have it, say ist, and I make the other thing 12 times

Comment: I have given you a starting point. Try to create different comparison functions and pass them into `qsort` the way I show below. If you run into trouble, you can try asking a new question.

Comment: @a.b_om I suggest that you study the duplicated question and try to come up with a solution that fits you. If you fail, post a new question that references the dup, explaining why it does not work, includes a [mre] and states the expected and actual behavior.

Comment: Please study [mre] carefully. It does not say "post all code you have". Creating an MRE is a process that takes some time, and it's a very good debugging tool.

Comment: I know, but if someone need it, he has it. And words that you not understand are Germanwords.

Comment: @klutt Please do not close questions providing references with bad code.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I looked a bit closer and you're right. Sorry.

Comment: @a.b_om Well, thing is, YOU are the one who needs help. That's why you should make it as easy as possible for us to help you. That includes minimizing the code to what is strictly needed to demonstrate your problem. Everything else just clutters the post. The procedure for doing what you want is equivalent irregardless if you have 2 or 12 fields in your struct. Also, translating identifiers greatly increase the readability for us. You have also missed the point with expected and actual behavior.

Comment: @klutt I know that I need helps. In my main method. I give the start pointer of the list to the method. Then I ask the user, by what he want to sort and if he want it Ascending or Descending. Then the method do it  and returns the New startpointer. And I have a problem to do it. I dont know how to do it. Thats is my problem. And I will translate the Germanwords. Wait please a moment.

Comment: So, its done. The code is for the understandig, how I want to make my program and you can intrepret the hole thing. This is my first project I make with C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Make an array

Create an array of pointers. Have the array members point to the list members. The code uses a little trick so that the last element of the list will get its `pNext` member set to NULL properly.

```
struYugiohCard *arr[size_of_list + 1], **arrp = arr, *iter;

for (iter = list; iter != NULL; iter = iter->pNext) {
    *arrp++ = iter;
}
*arrp = NULL;
```

#### Write a comparison function, then call `qsort`

There are lots of examples of how to use `qsort`, but the trick is writing an appropriate comparison function. It is important to realize that `qsort` will pass in the addresses of the array elements it is comparing. Since our array contains pointers, the comparison function will be passed pointers to pointers.

In your case, I would guess `CardType2 Ascending` might be implemented using `strcmp`, which has return values that match up to what `qsort` expects (negative if `a` is less than `b`, positive if greater than, zero if equal):

```
int cmp_CardType2_Ascending(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const struYugiohCard * const *aa = a;
    const struYugiohCard * const *bb = b;
    return strcmp((*aa)->CardType2, (*bb)->CardType2);
}

//...

qsort(arr, size_of_list, sizeof(*arr), cmp_CardType2_Ascending);
```

#### Fix your `list`

Now, rewire your list to the sorted order. Notice the `pNext` of the last iteration is making use of the extra array member which was set to NULL.

```
arr[0]->pNext = arr[1];
arr[0]->pPrev = NULL;
for (int i = 1; i < size_of_list; ++i) {
    arr[i]->pNext = arr[i+1];
    arr[i]->pPrev = arr[i-1];
}
list = arr[0];
```

#### Putting it into a function

Below is a function that puts most of this logic into a single function. The sorting function is passed in, and this function is then passed to `qsort`.

```
void sort_YugiohCard(struYugiohCard **pList, int size_of_list,
                     int (*By)(const void *, const void *)) {

    if (size_of_list == 0) return;

    struYugiohCard *list = *pList;
    struYugiohCard *arr[size_of_list+1], **arrp = arr, *iter;

    for (iter = list; iter != NULL; iter = iter->pNext)
        *arrp++ = iter;
    *arrp = NULL;

    qsort(arr, size_of_list, sizeof(*arr), By);

    arr[0]->pNext = arr[1];
    arr[0]->pPrev = NULL;
    for (int i = 1; i < size_of_list; ++i) {
        arr[i]->pNext = arr[i+1];
        arr[i]->pPrev = arr[i-1];
    }
    list = arr[0];

    *pList = list;
}
```

Then, you can call this function like this:

```
sort_YugiohCard(&list, 5, cmp_CardType2_Ascending);
```

And the list will be returned in sorted order as determined by the comparison function.

#### A demo

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVXRbtowFH3PV3hMnRySVAHal6VUArq9AFW1dQ9rhlAIhlqDJHMctG7i27trx0lsmk6TlgfgHp/jc@/1dYi9bRw/v6VJvCvWBF3lfE3T88dry4B2dHWKMZpsBWbxp4ysyQYBVMQcfS22NH2cRGyNflsInvgxYug22pOw5/uLoMEE5x7EYb@CacLRjBzIrgk/Rcn3JrojybrYFfvPPNoSTUN10uh@2gQ3Hz5qlncszQjjT42lhOdpknPCZDIXrTn2w4GB35A8ZjTjNE3Cy7qsFy3oouyW/OSvr94xcgiso1xrFgLLMgE0DS8XaKg6GvryNzqvs4Ow8/Dw0HHRuTSEeOr0RCQMIPJBdnRLda9NPZ/PTXVfU08dv1b329Sj0chUDwx1r1YP2tSTycRUXxjqfq2@aFOPx2Nd7bvA1NQDoT4G1rOYhnifLWvxcpTHME8wxzgWA4AOKV2jbuQiPVzZ1RxL8ORcugruRhG4RcE/MFcrYK5KJiO8YImgQmYYwy62d10n6CIMbB2xYVYsSyaWp4wvtf3xqV83m9Gcu/IW5PQXWaab5U4g0vnFI2i4O36yjWaYvbBFL8qrtQFDbVM0hM7bqp7AquddT6jkoTKvoJUSMRbq2zq9hQuVAJyJ9jIGEYWbqhw2KUNYxLAo6AGSwZshuv0ym6loKL@8azkgdl283NRx1HKZTmUk1aXFD9FnLJ2NJsoo3WAhsV0EfVMCUYK/UHZl0nDjAnNNTWfp01QCR0AB7kHm6MrwC5Dj0GoSq63oiQ11KiODocxk7FWMo/xUR1LmpQooz6fqaD1vGbzw9YHDbcdbZXi61rQ4K3iOO57ndezgv89Q5rTBnbPsPTrLvyXwHhA8V7HNayNfAPuIJgi/lqZqh/r7eFGxrFANrnn78LtyKC7d114x9t/3PD7/AQ)

Comment: Is that C++? I think, that is C++. I don't know.

Comment: It is C. Answer updated for your doubly linked lists.

Comment: Ok. I'll try it.

Comment: Reading the data into an array of struct, sorting the array with `qsort` and then adding the sorted structs to your list will be *Orders of Magnitude* faster than scanning the list on each *insert* to insert the nodes in sorted order. Answer is right-on-point.